# Edge-Side-Includes Module for nginx?

Tags: http, caching, proxy, nginx, edge-side-includes

Does anyone know about an ESI 1.0 implementation for nginx?

Comment: Once again the close nazis have ruined a perfectly good question.

Comment: I also have this question, seems perfectly normal to me...maybe belongs on server fault?